# FQL Query incorrectly returns exactly 100 results after working for months

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have an FQL query that queries a list of photos. For months, it was working as expected, returning ~450 photos from the following query:

```
SELECT object_id,src FROM photo WHERE owner=me()
```

All of a sudden, however, the results appear capped at 100 - that is, only the most 100 results are returned.

I know this is not a client code error - an iOS app in my case - because this is happening in my production code which has NOT been updated since working correctly.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know the cause of this issue, but I have discovered a simple workaround: add a very high `limit` parameter to the query.

Example:

```
SELECT object_id,src FROM photo WHERE owner=me() limit 1000
```

If your results total less than the `limit` value, then the expected number is returned (in my case roughly ~450).

NOTE: There may be an maximum `limit` value allowed by Facebook. For example, let's pretend you expected 10,000+ results - would FQL accept a limit of 20,000? I don't know. If you encounter this, please post your results.

Comment: I have tested and now use a `limit` of 10,000 in my production app and it seems to be working OK.